# Creating functions in a quick way in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

As you know, in codeigniter a function name in a class becomes url like :

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {  

    function sayHello() {

        echo "Hello";  

    }  

}
```

To display the content of function simply you can show it by using:

```
www.mydomain.com/example/sayhello
```

My question is, instead of writing all my function names one by one, how can i form these functions using a loop or by fetching function names from database? For example, i have 100 function name in my database. is it possible to do it writing clear and short code or should i write all functions manually? Thanks...

Comment: Ok, wait a moment: what's the reason for that?

Comment: meta-programming? Also, why? I suspect what you're looking for can be done much better using arguments and modified routes.

Comment: because in my university classs, there must be university-name functions. so i can call .com/university/university-name... i want to arrange like this. so i must create functions how many university there are

Comment: You can achiede the same with university($name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with creating functions. Your problem is routing. Solve that:

```
class University extends CI_Controller {

    public function _remap( $university_name )
    {

    }

}
```

More info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping